# Regex excluding string starting with # and # following with multiple spaces and tabs

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm pretty new to regex and now I'm trying to write a regex to retrieve a string in the following scenario in python package `re`

```
module load ABC => true
#(spaces) module load DEF => false
#(tabs) module load GHI => false
#(spaces+tabes) module load JKL => false
module load MNO => false (already find one match)
```

Is it possible to do it with python `re` regex package?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the regex string you're using?

Comment: You need to edit to do a better job of explaining what you want to do. Among other things do not confuse strings with results. Presumably you are giving five examples of strings. If so, each needs to be a valid Ruby string. I assume the first is `"module load ABC"`. If so, write it that way (including the quotes). Presumably you are you "retrieving" that entire string. Why? If your example is of a single string with five lines, Place double quotes at the beginning of the first line and at the end of the last line, after stripping out all the `" => true"` and `" false"` bits.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work: `/^(?!#\s+.*).*$/gm`

In Python :

```py
import re
regex = r"^(?!#\s+.*).*$"
```

You can run it here: https://regex101.com/r/Tpy7Ct/1

Explanation of the regular expression:

- Matching a line beginning can be done with `^` meaning "starting with"
  and the `m` flag for multiline, which will make the `^` match the
  beginning of a line instead of the beginning of the full string.
- Same for `$` which will match the end of a line instead of the end
  of the full string, as we have the `m` flag enabled.
- The `g` flag is for **g**lobal, and it means that it doesn't stop
  at the first occurrence but continues searching.
- `.` is to match any char (except new lines as we didn't enable the
  `s` flag). As it's followed by `*`, this means that it can be repeated
  0 or n times. So the idea of this part of the pattern is to match all
  the line with `^.*$`. But we don't want to match all lines as comments
  should be ignored.
- This is what brings us to the use of a **negative lookahead**, meaning
  that we want to check what's coming next, and we don't want to match
  the hashtag followed by spaces or tabs. A negative lookahead is done
  with `(?!   )` and you then put inside what you don't want to find.
- We don't want to find "#" followed by spaces or tabs. Spaces or tabs
  could be matched with `\s` which is "space characters". It would match
  new lines, but it shouldn't be a problem here. You said at least a
  space or a tab or both. So this is why we add the `+` sign after to
  say that it should be one or multiple times.

  We could be more precise and use a list of chars with `[ \t]` to
  explicitly say "only a normal space or a tab". The negative lookahead
  should be placed just after the beginning of the line so just after
  the `^` pattern. In this case the regex would become
  `/^(?!#[ \t]+.*).*$/gm`.

A few questions about your case:

- I don't know if you are allowed to have spaces before the hashtag.
  If it's the case, then add `\s*` in front of the hashtag.
- Is it possible to have a line with a hashtag and nothing behind?
  If yes, then replace the `+` sign by `*` after the spaces following
  the hashtag.
- Do you want to match an empty line? If no, then replace `.*` by `.+`.

This would lead to this regex :

`/^(?![ \t]*#[ \t]*.+).+$/gm`

See why by testing it here: https://regex101.com/r/Ut8H4m/2

Use regex101's code generator on the left to
**show you the *Python* code**. [Run the Python code here](https://www.online-python.com/OrHBPtQbpR)